# C++ const iterator C2662

Tags: c++, iterator, constants

Having problems iterating.  Problem has to do with const correctness, I think.  I assume B::getGenerate() should be const for this code to work, but I don't have control over B::getGenerate().

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
jbu

Code follows:

```
int
A::getNumOptions() const
{
   int running_total = 0;

   BList::const_iterator iter = m_options.begin();

   while(iter != m_options.end())
   {
      if(iter->getGenerate()) //this is the line of the error; getGenerate() returns bool; no const in signature
      {
         running_total++;
      }
   }

   return running_total;
}
```

1>.\A.cpp(118) : error C2662: 'B::getGenerate()' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const B' to 'B &'

Comment: I assume that in reality you do advance the iter after the if-statement inside the while loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if `getGenerate` is non-const, your iterator must be non-const. And if that's the case, your `getNumOptions` will also have to be non-const.

If `getGenerate` isn't under you control, there isn't anything else you can do. But if that method *could be* `const`, bring it up with whoever implemented that method; tell them it should be `const`.

Comment: thanks! duh. I get your explanation and had a feeling it was that...I just (for no reason) thought I had more control over whether the methods that I wrote were const or not.

Answer (score 1):

B::getGenerate() needs to be declared like this:

```
class B
{
   bool getGenerate() const;
};
```

The 'const' keyword is the important bit here.  This tells the compiler that calling getGenerate() will not modify any of the other members of B.